# Is the integral $\intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx$ absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I'm trying to solve the next problem: Determine if $\intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx$
is absolutetly convergent, conditionally covergent or diverges.

I think that the integral is abosolutely convergent and I tried to
do this: For all $x\geq0$ is true that
$$
\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}\leq\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{3}}}=\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}.
$$

Then, using the fact that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx$
is convergent for $\alpha>1$ and the comparison test we can conclude
that the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx$
is absolutely convergent. Also, since the function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}$
is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ then is Riemann integrable on $\left[0,1\right]$.
Therefore,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx.$$

And then, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx$
is convergent since in the last equality, the two sumands on the right
side are finite. Thus, the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx$
is absolutely convergent.

I don't know if what I did is right. Could you help me checking or
giving me some suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you having doubts?

Comment: I have a little doubt where I separated the integral as the sum of those two integrals.

Comment: Here:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mid\cos x\mid}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}dx.$$

Comment: That's perfectly fine. You can convince yourself by writing $\int_0^\infty$ as $\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. As you correctly noted, the absolute value of the integrand is continuous on $\Bbb R^+$; and thus in particular Riemann-integrable on any (bounded) interval $[0,I]\subset\Bbb R$.

Also, because you want to prove absolute convergence, your first inequality should be stated as 
$$\left|\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}\right|\le\frac{|\cos x|}{\sqrt{1+x^{3}}}.$$

Comment: Alright, thanks.